# Help with Kanto mount, 55" tv, and 24" between studs

Tags: walls, installation, plywood, television, mount

I want to mount my 55" tv (39.2 lbs) on a Kanto mount (https://web.archive.org/web/20170317095158/http://www.kantoliving.com/product/pdx680/) but the studs are spaced 24" apart. I've been doing some reading and from what I've gathered I'd have to use a 3/4" plywood to reinforce the gap and tv. Any suggestions on what I need?

Correction, the wall mount is the Kanto PDX650 (https://web.archive.org/web/20170418215212/http://kantoliving.com:80/product/pdx650 which is made for studs with 16") spacing not the PDX680. Sorry.

Comment: Kanto claims that it can be used on studs up to 24" apart (assuming you can position it to hit 2 studs). However, full extension of a mount of this type puts a lot of strain on the mounting support. I would reinforce with plywood or at least a 1x6 board bolted into studs.

Comment: I just remounted a similar tv with a similar mount at my office. Four 3/16" lag screws held it in place, rock solid. I have no concerns using that particular mount alone with your tv, even at 24" centers (it's rated for 125 lbs., after all). I'd try that before making things needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to hang one studs that are 24" apart so.  I have a 60" TV hung on 24" studs.   As long as the steel mount is spanned across two studs and securely fastened to the studs (with lag bolts), you'll be fine.

**Edit:** 
Well, now that your answer says the specs are only for 16" studs (and after reading the specs, it shows the wall plate is only 21"), then, NO, this won't work obviously.  You'll need a different wall plate that can accomodate the span of two studs.  I would not attempt to make this work unless you get crafty with a welder (it isn't worth it, buy a different plate).  You need it spanned across two studs, with very strong fasteners.  Considering this is a swivel out mount, it will put great stress on your fasteners, and they need to be lag bolts into studs.